# How get 'product_name' with Attribute Value, but without Attribute Group in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I call in PS 1.7.4:

```
SELECT psod.*, msod.*, pl.`name` as `product_name`,
    pl.`description`, pl.`link_rewrite` 
FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_detail` as psod
```

and if I want to write it on page, I use:

```
{$product_detail['product_name']}
```

The problem is that I get only the short product name, without the Attribute value (eg.: Mobile phone). If I delete `pl.name as product_name` I get the long product name with Attribute Group and Attribute Value (eg.: Mobile Phone - Type : for older).

But my goal is getting Product name - Attribute Value (eg.: Mobile Phone - for older) without the Attribute Group.

What should I change?

Comment: you miss some parts of the select statement. Write please the complete select statement

Comment: DELETE FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'dpcz_cart`
                WHERE id_cart = ' . (int) $sp532624); } public static function getWkPsProduct($sp598fdf) { return Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT * FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'wk_mp_seller_product`
            WHERE `id_ps_product` =' . (int) $sp598fdf); } public static function getWkProductDetailFromOrder($spa8973c, $sp286c1a, $spef3ab7) { return Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT psod.*, msod.*, pl.`description`, pl.`link_rewrite` FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_detail` as psod
          JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'wk_mp_seller_order_detail` as msod

Comment: ON (psod.`product_id` = msod.`product_id` AND psod.`product_attribute_id` = msod.`product_attribute_id` AND psod.`id_order` = msod.`id_order`)
          LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product` msp ON (msp.`id_product` = psod.`product_id`)
          LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_lang` pl ON (msp.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $spef3ab7 . ' )

Comment: please edit your question instead of writing in the comment

Comment: WHERE psod.`id_order`=' . (int) $spa8973c . ' AND psod.`product_id`=' . (int) $sp286c1a)[0]; } public static function getCoverImageLink($sp70641c, $spb388a2) { $sp4300f0 = Image::getCover($sp70641c); $speb4fc4 = new Link(); $sp96619e = $speb4fc4->getImageLink($spb388a2, $sp4300f0['id_image']); return '//' . $sp96619e; } public static function getByCustomerId($sp5ae6e8) { try { $sp8baee4 = Configuration::get('PS_OS_WS_PAYMENT');

Comment: return Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT pso.id_order, dpczc.* FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` AS pso JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'dpcz_cart` AS dpczc ON (pso.`id_cart` = dpczc.`id_cart`)
            WHERE pso.`current_state` = ' . (int) $sp8baee4 . ' AND pso.`id_customer` = ' . $sp5ae6e8); } catch (Exception $spcb801f) { } } public function setUsed() { $this->date_used = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); return Db::getInstance()->update('dpcz_cart', array('date_used' => $this->date_used), "`id` = {$this->id}"); } }

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

{$product_detail['product_name']|replace:"Type :":" "}